# jQuery popout div next to element of my choice

Tags: jquery, popup

I am looking for a jquery library that will let me create a pop out div under an element of my choice. What I am looking for is very similar to [the jquery ui date picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), but it will not have the date picker by default. I want to be able to put my content into it.

popout #popout under #textbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works but you have to click in the text-box again to hide it. Though this can be sorted out easily:

```
<div id="divPop" style="z-index:500;position:absolute;display:none">
    Hello World! This is Popup Div.
</div>
<input id="txt" type="text" value="" width="200px" height="50px" 
    style="border:2px solid #ffeeee;color:#eeeeff;background-color:#aaeeaa"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txt").popupDiv("#divPop");
    });
</script>
```

---

```
jQuery.fn.popupDiv = function (divToPop) {
    var pos=$(this).offset();
    var h=$(this).height();
    var w=$(this).width();

    $(divToPop).css({ left: pos.left + w + 10, top: pos.top + h + 10 });

    $(this).click(function(e) {
        $(divToPop).css({ left: pos.left + w + 10, top: pos.top + h + 10 });
        if ($(divToPop).css('display') !== 'none') {
            $(divToPop).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(divToPop).show();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Note that you can use $(divToPop).toggle() to toggle whether the element is hidden instead of your if/else.  A little cleaner and (probably) less brittle.

Answer (score 1):

You could hand roll one like this:

```
<div>
  <span onclick="popout(this)">Click Here</span>
  <div class="mypopout"></div>
</div>

function popout(ele) {
   $(ele).next('.mypopout').html('some html');
   $(ele).next('.mypopout').toggle();
}
```

Comment: Separate function call from HTML and put it inside script tag.

Comment: Just if you could have added css to 'some html' to make it look like a popup.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one to use:
http://jquery.iceburg.net/jqModal/

Very easy and lots of options.