# dynamically show/hide div based on the input of textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a website,
I have a page containing a list of persons built like this:

```
<div class="personsMenu">
    <div class="person">
        <div class="name">John</div>
        <div class="age">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <div class="name">Kate</div>
        <div class="age">24</div>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <div class="name">Tom</div>
        <div class="age">17</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have a textbox `<input type="Text" id="filterTextBox"/>`

Using jquery i need to do the following:

When the user start typing in the textbox the divs where the "name" does not contain the characters disappears (some sort of a dynamic filter, you only see the persons who's name contains the written characters)

So the logic should be like this:

When the user type a character in the textbox (or remove one) we loop through all the "person" divs and if the "name" div inside that "person" contains the characters we show it, otherwise we hide it (.show() and .hide() in jquery)

And of course if the textbox is empty we show everything.

Can this be done?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes this can be done, what have you tried so far with jQuery (what code do you have)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At every keystroke, you could `.toggle()` each `.person`, passing a variable indicating whether or not it matches the current value, and should thus be shown.

```
$('.my-textbox').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp('^' + value, 'i');

    $('.personsMenu .person').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('.name', this).text());
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
});​
```

Modify the expression as you see fit. In this version, it checks that the name *starts* with the value entered, and ignores casing.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tV9RK/)

Comment: How can I get this to work by also checking the children of those elements? But, only hiding the entire box. So like if there are tags within the div it searches all the tags and hides/shows the entire div based on that. My testing keeps getting me weird results.

Comment: @BryantFrankford: If I'm understanding you correctly, it ought to be enough to make sure for every match, that all of its ancestor nodes are also visible. Check out the `if(isMatch)` part of [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p53gsa3d/)

Comment: what does mean by new i (RegExp('^' + value, 'i');). what i have to do for entire text search. Above code is running but matching with start text. i want match text anywhere in text line

Comment: @Inderjeet: the `^` matches start of string. Use `RegExp(value, 'i')`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started. I'm sure it's far from perfect, but you haven't shown what you've already tried and what's gone wrong in your question.

```
$("#filterTextBox").on("keyup", function () {
    var search = this.value;
    $(".person").show().filter(function () {
        return $(".name", this).text().indexOf(search) < 0;
    }).hide();        
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Da4mX/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with **jQuery** I would highly recommend their [**Autocomplete** UI Control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).  I've used it on several projects and you can update the search function to use a local datastore such as this.  As a side note, you might want to consider using `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s...

**Code Example**

```
//Search-As-You-Type
$(id).find('input').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {},
    select: function( event, ui ) {},
    source: function(request, response){
        //here is where you want to call your custom function
        findSite(request.term);             
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
  var value = this.value
  $('.person')
    .hide()
    .children('.name')
    .filter(function(){
      var re = new RegExp(value)
      return re.test($(this).text())
    })
    .parent()
    .show()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i need this type of work, and i find a nice solution. See this [jQuery popout div next to element of my choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746330/jquery-popout-div-next-to-element-of-my-choice)

Answer (score 0):

This code search Entire String

```
$( '#input-text' ).keyup( function () {
    var value = $( this ).val();
   $( '#filter-parant > .filter-div' ).each( function () {
        $('.filter-div:contains("' + value + '")').show();
        $('.filter-div:not(:contains("' + value + '"))').hide();

    } );
} );
```

**I Hope this will help you**

Answer (score -1):

Here's a script you should consider I use and created. You should also use `<ul>` and `<li>`.

```
(function($){
    $.tzFilter = function(jq, phrase, type, column, ifHidden){
        var new_hidden = false;
        if(this.last_phrase === phrase){
            return false;
        }

        if(!type){
            type = 'ul';
        }

        var phrase_length = phrase.length;
        var words = phrase.toLowerCase().split(' ');

        var matches = function(elem){
            elem.show()
        }
        var noMatch = function(elem){
            elem.hide();
            new_hidden = true
        }
        var getText = function(elem){
            return elem.text()
        }

        if(column){
            var index = null;
            if(type == 'table'){
                jq.find('thead > tr:last > th').each( function(i){
                    if( $.trim($(this).text()) == column ){
                        index = i; return false;
                    }
                });
            } else if (type == 'ul'){
                jq.find("li").each(function(i){
                    if(!$(this).attr('display', 'none')){
                        if( $.trim($(this).text()) == column ){
                        index = i; return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            if(index == null){
                throw('Index non trouvée: ' + column + '')
            }

            if(type == 'table'){
                getText = function(elem){
                    return jQuery(elem.find(('td:eq(' + index + ')')  )).text();
                }
            } else if (type == 'ul') {
                getText = function(elem){
                    return jQuery(elem.find(('"li:eq(' + index + ')')  )).text();
                }
            }
        }

        // On a simplement ajouté une lettre, on va regarder pour le nouveau mot, sans devoir tout regarder à nouveau
        if((words.size > 1) && (phrase.substr(0, phrase_length - 1) === this.last_phrase)){
            if(phrase[-1] === ' '){
                this.last_phrase = phrase;
                return false;
            }

            // On va chercher uniquement pour le nouveau mot
            var words = words[-1];

            // On cache uniquement les tables visibles
            matches = function(elem) {;}

            if(type == 'table'){
                var elems = jq.find('tbody > tr:visible');
            } else if (type == 'ul'){
                var elems = jq.find('li:visible');
            }
        } else {
            new_hidden = true;

            if(type == 'table'){
                var elems = jq.find('tbody > tr')
            } else if (type == 'ul') {
                var elems = jq.find('li')
            }
        }


        elems.each(function(){
            var elem = $(this);
            $.tzFilter.has_words(getText(elem), words, false) ? matches(elem) : noMatch(elem);
        });

        last_phrase = phrase;

        if(ifHidden && new_hidden){
            ifHidden();
        }
        return jq;
    };

    // On cache pour accélérer le tout
    $.tzFilter.last_phrase = ""

    $.tzFilter.has_words = function(str, words, caseSensitive){
        var text = caseSensitive ? str : str.toLowerCase();
        for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++){
            if(text.indexOf(words[i]) === -1){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
})(jQuery);
```