# Dynamically show/hide div based on first "n" types of input field

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an input field which filters my divs as the user types, like this

[dynamically show/hide div based on the input of textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229133/dynamically-show-hide-div-based-on-the-input-of-textbox/11229297#11229297)

I need an upgrade: the input field length has no limits, but the JavaScript should just consider the first 8 letters/numbers typed by the user and ignore the rest.

For example, on a div like this:

```
<div class="name">Katekate</div>
```

If the user types "katekate" or "katekatekate" the result is the same.

I think I should use the "substring" function, but I am getting crazy to solve the problem.
Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Please include the code you tried with `substring` so someone can tell you how to fix your code.

Comment: So your problem is that input field has no lenght limit? Why don't you implement limit? If user can type more and that does not affect filtering than it will cause confusion.

Comment: @IvanIvanić no the field is used for a sku code which allows to show/hide several groups of parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div:

```
<div class="name">Katekate</div>
```

In javascript

```
$(".name").val().substr(0, 8);
```

Result: only the 8 first letters/numbers got caught

Comment: It wasn't very clear but it gave me the solution, it works great! Thanks! 
`code $(this).val().substr(0, 8);`